# Can connect to PI via eth0 in SSH but not wlan0

Tags: raspbian, networking, wifi

I have raspbian installed on my Raspberry Pi with a working network adapter. I have setup my */etc/network/interfaces* file like the following

```
auto lo

iface lo inet loopback
iface eth0 inet dhcp

iface eth0 inet static
        address 192.168.1.100
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        gateway 192.168.1.1

allow-hotplug wlan0

iface wlan0 inet static
        address 192.168.2.200
        netmask 255.255.255.0

wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf

allow-hotplug wlan1

iface wlan1 inet static
        address 192.168.42.1
        netmask 255.255.255.0

up iptables-restore < /etc/iptables.ipv4.nat
```

I am able to connect through SSH at **address 192.168.1.100**(which is ethernet - eth0), but I cannot seem to connect to SSH at **address 192.168.2.200**(which is wifi - wlan0)

- I have tried changing the last address end decimals many times encase
  the number is reserved, but the problem still persists.
- I have tried rebooting the system 4 times

*ifconfig -a* shows that **wlan0** does have an IP assigned to it

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:00:00:00:00:22
          inet addr:192.168.1.6  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:2032 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1353 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:1973327 (1.8 MiB)  TX bytes:646906 (631.7 KiB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:10 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:10 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:500 (500.0 B)  TX bytes:500 (500.0 B)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 22:22:22:22:22:22
          inet addr:192.168.2.200  Bcast:192.168.2.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:10 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:2 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:1584 (1.5 KiB)  TX bytes:288 (288.0 B)
```

**netstat -nlt** returns

```
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3389            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:21              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3350          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
```

**iptables -L -nv** returns

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 72 packets, 4383 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 50 packets, 6512 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

Comment: Can you ping the RPi at both addresses?

Comment: When I run ping from a windows machine, I get a reply from 192.168.1.100 but *request timed out* from 192.168.2.200. What does this indicate

Comment: I'm going to guess that the Windows machine is connected to the 192.168.1.0/24 wired subnet, right? Try this: Connect to your 192.168.2.0/24 network and try pinging 192.168.2.200. Connect to your 192.168.1.0/24 network and try pinging the 192.168.1.100 address. If you can ping the "local" IP but never the IP on another subnet, you are lacking a route to get to the other subnet. If you want to route *through* the RPi, Martin's advice below applies... *If the RPi is either your default gateway, or routes to your other router*. Otherwise, your normal router is needs a route to both subnets.

Comment: @bobstro You have found the issue, however I was able to discover this by changing my **wlan0** config like *address 192.168.1.200*, as this is apart of the same subnet as **eth0** it now allows me to connect. Is it possible for me to have the **wlan0** on another subnet? The problem is having them on the same subnet causes confict with **isc-dhcp-server** - as this software cannot run interfaces on the same subnet. So I have to sacrifice one over the other, which I cannot do. Thanks for your input

Comment: I'm not clear on what you're trying to do. You have `isc-dhcp-server` on your RPi and it's conflicting with your existing dhcp server perhaps? You have two main options using two interfaces (or more) on the RPi: Bridge the traffic (wlan0 and eth0 are same network, one subnet typically) or route (wlan0 and eth0 are different networks, different subnets). If routing, you can do NAT and other firewall tricks. Perhaps it would be best if you simply elaborated on what you're trying to do in the end.

Comment: what WiFi Adapter are you using please specify

Comment: Do you have both ip addresses in your ~/.ssh/known_hosts file?

Answer (score 1):

Another solution would be to use a bridge.

No need for the wifi to have it's own IP.

You can do

`sudo apt-get install bridge-utils`

Then

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet manual

auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet manual

auto br0
iface br0 inet static
        bridge_ports eth0 wlan0
        address 192.168.1.100
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        gateway 192.168.1.1
```

`eth0` and `wlan0` will share the same IP and act as one interface.

If it works with one interface it should work with the other.

You can also add wlan1 easily with `bridge_ports eth0 wlan0 wlan1`

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you have a routing problem. From which IP address are you trying to connect to the wifi's IP? If you're not in the same network as the interface you're trying to connect to, then you'll need to activate IP forwarding on the pi:

```
root@pi# sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
```

Also, are you sure that the machine you're trying to connect from (aka 'ssh-client') knows how to find its way to the pi's wifi network? If the pi is not the default gateway, you have to set the route accordingly:

```
user@ssh-client$ sudo ip route add 192.168.2.0/24 via 192.168.1.6
```

If the routing is fine, can you confirm that sshd on the pi actually is listening on all the neccessary IPs?

```
user@pi$ netstat -nlt
```

should show a line like this:

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
```

Check /etc/ssh/sshd_config on the pi for interesting settings.

Finally, the firwall on either the pi or the ssh-client might be in your way. You can check them with 
`iptables -L -nv`.

Hope this points you in the right direction,
Martin

Comment: thanks, I have updated my original post with many of your cmds and there output. I am still trying to find a solution, planning to remove some of the other connections I have in my pi to attempt elimination process.